# angular bootstrap popover hide after few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, click, popover

This is my html code:

```
<li class="pop" popover="popover text goes here" popover-trigger="mousedown">
    <a><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
</li>
```

When clicking the icon a popover is opened as expected.
Currenly the popover is close only by click on the icon.
I wish that the popover will be closed automaticaly after few seconds.

This is my javascript code - which does not work:

```
$('.pop').popover().click(function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
     $('.pop').popover('hide');
   }, 4000);
});
```

when running

```
$('.pop').popover()
```

on FF debugger I getting:

```
typeError: undefined is not a function
```

Please help :)

Comment: Can you prepare a demo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by [@dfsq's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219771/867480) about `tt_isOpen`, you could create a custom directive to do the auto hiding.

```
.directive('popoverAutoclose', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var timeoutHandle;

      scope.$watch('tt_isOpen', function (isOpen) {
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutHandle);

        if (isOpen) {
          timeoutHandle = $timeout(function () {
            scope.tt_isOpen = false;
          }, +attrs.popoverAutoclose || 5000);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<li class="pop" popover="popover text goes here" popover-autoclose="2000" popover-trigger="mousedown">
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KQKHtz73lFk8Z4g4q6a4?p=preview

Comment: I would say this is how it should be done. Instead of messing with controller like in my example. This approach is the only true.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can do it I can think of is a little weird, but working. Add `ngMousedown` handler to your `LI` element and define a handler for it in controller:

```
<li class="pop" popover="popover text goes here" ng-mousedown="mousedown()" popover-trigger="mousedown">
    <a><i class="icon-link"></i> Link</a>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.mousedown = function() {
    var tooltipScope = this;
    $timeout(function() {
        tooltipScope.tt_isOpen = false;
    }, 2000);
};
```

The idea is that AngularUI's popover uses `$tooltip` service internally, which defined a bunch of internal properties in the scope of the element. One of those properties is `tt_isOpen`. If you set it to `false` tooltip will hide.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/T1Uouba0MU2vtcwuRPt9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to create a variable that is a boolean, and give it a True/False values, and if you clicked on the pop-up a method will be called throw the controller and will be a timeout that flips the variable to a False. This variable will be used in the tag "ng-show" to show and hide.

Best Regards