# angular bootstrap popover hide after few seconds : tt_isOpen variable removed in ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to used the excellent directive code of [runTarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867480/runtarm) about [angular-bootstrap-popover-hide-after-few-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25220581/1787983).

There's no problem with [ui-bootstrap 0.11.0.js](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js) but in [ui-bootstrap-0.12.0](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js) **tt_isOpen is removed** and replaced by a property : isOpen of an isolated scope : var ttScope = scope.$new(true).
I didn't succeed to access the right variable to watch to in place of tt_isOpen.
 All this is very frustrating.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Find this row in tpls.js:

```
var ttScope = scope.$new(true);
```

And replace with:

```
var ttScope = scope;
```

Also little higher, after:

```
restrict: 'EA',
```

Add next property:

```
scope: true,
```

Now you can access to element scope by:

```
angular.element('#123').scope().isOpen = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

tt_open used to be associated with the element that opened the tooltip, now isOpen is associated with the tooltip itself.

You can use the following to find the tooltip element and mark it as closed.

```
angular.element('.tooltip').scope().$parent.isOpen = false;
```